Files disappearing from ntfs drive
I recently purchased a 4tb nvme to upgrade the existing 2tb drive data drive in my windows machine and in order to transfer my data over I created a small 100gb partition on the 2tb drive put it in my laptop and installed ubuntu 24.04.1 on the 100gb partition.
I then put the 4tb drive in my windows system formatted it and created an ntfs filesystem on it.
After that was done I took the drive and installed it in my laptop and tried copying the files from the 1.9tb ntfs partition on my old drive to the new drive.
Everything appeared fine and all the data seemed to have copied over successfully I even unmounted and remounted the drive and it appeared fine but when I reinstalled it in my windows machine it did not detect anything on the new drive and when I reinstalled it in my laptop to see if ubuntu could still see it, it also could not see any files although it could see that 1.9tb where in use unlike my windows machine.
Is there something that I am missing? Why would the drive behave this way? Is there some kind of compatibility issue that I am not seeing?

So to understand correctly, you copied files from one NTFS drive to another using Ubuntu and not Windows? I would think it would be best to use Windows to do this, and thus not be on-topic here.

@ArturMeinild the reason that I used ubuntu to do this was because it is very easy and quick to install and I saw no reason as to why it would have any trouble with the task

My advice would simply be to try and copy the files using Windows. I think the Linux NTFS driver only supports up to Windows Server 2019 / Windows 10. Read more here: https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g

@ArturMeinild I was not aware of this issue I appreciate the info, I will try it with windows instead I guess

If you want to use the drive in both Ubuntu and Windows, use exFAT instead of NTFS

Did Windows have fast startup on, which sets hibernation flag. & then restore of hibernation erases anything done outside of it? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
